# How to get an 11 alphanumeric UNIQUE ID from a digit-only string?

Tags: java, algorithm, uniqueidentifier

- I have an original string which can be either a 12-digit string OR a 19-digit customer ID which also includes digits only. Both cases are unique.
- For the sake of the question, let's assume that we're dealing with a 12-digit string and if you suggest a solution then it must fit also to the 19-digit case.
- Our client wants us to create a SECOND unique string which its length needs to be 11 chars, (whether the original string is the 12-digit one OR the 19-digit one); this unique string/ID  should include alpha-numeric chars, where 'alpha' means that all letters can be a part of it; i.e. a solution in which the "participating" chars are digits only + lower case letters from 'a' to 'e' is not enough as it gives us less options then when using all lower & upper letters.
- Note that I don't need encryption, but a UNIQUE capability.
- I would appreciate any help, preferred with an example or a link to an example.
- If someones knows of a third party package that address such case, then please leave a link for it.
  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding regarding the unique; I edited my original question... Regarding your answer, I couldn't understand how this reduces the original length to 11. Thanks in advance...

Comment: So, any other suggestions? I don't mind having a third-party JAR/package for this issue. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does the 11 char string need to be readable or can it contain any characters? In the end 11 digits and "normal" letters (small and large caps) can represent a 19 digits number so it can be done ((26+26+10)**11)

Comment: It should be alphanumeric only, (digits + letters).

Comment: @boomboom, did u find the solution yet, i'm facing the same problem now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way you can try.

Make your 12-digit to binary presentation, which should be able to represented by 5-bytes.  Use base64 to encode it and it should be able to be represented by 9 alpha-numeric character. (ok... base64 did contains several non-alpha-numeric char... :P )

(If you have difficulties making it a 5-byte representation, breaking that 12 digits to 3 groups of 4 digits, each represent by 2 bytes should work too)

Search for base64 and get some understanding about it, then you may implement your own encoding method in similar manner.

---

Adding some code:
(not tested, just give u an idea on it looks like)

```
String originalId= "123456789012";

String resultString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(new BigInteger(originalId).toByteArray());
```

Comment: I edited my question; I got feedback that it wasn't clear enough - please take a look again, thanks in advance...

Comment: The idea is the same.  What you need is change present your 19-digit BASE-10 integer value in form of BASE-64 (or BASE-62 as suggested in another question, if u need strict alpha-numeric).  The reason for me to suggest BASE-64 is because it is built-in and quick.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer proposed to use BigInteger with a radix of 36, but that will not be enough for 19 digits.

I don't know if there are libraries to convert to/from base 62, but the contrived example below gives you an idea of how you could do it. The output is:

> originalId = 999999999999999999
>   newId = bUI6zOLZTrh
>   retrieveOriginalId = 999999999999999999

The rationale of using base 62 is as follows:

- if the original number is unique, the new one will be unique too because they are the same number really (i.e. there is a one-to-one relationship)
- you can represent `N ^ 11` 11-char numbers in base N (for example, in base 10, an 11-digit number can be between 0 and 10 ^ 11 or 100 billion)
- the largest 19 digit number (in base 10) is 10 ^ 19 - 1
- with N = 62, you have 62 ^ 11 = 5 * 10 ^ 19 possibilities, which is larger than 10 ^ 19 and can therefore represent any 19-digit numbers. Actually using base 54 would be enough.

Sample code (algorithms inspired from BigInteger and Long classes - exception handling to be added):

```
class Base62 {

    private static final BigInteger RADIX = BigInteger.valueOf(62);
    private static final char[] DIGITS = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
        '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b',
        'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
        'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
        'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
        'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
        'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
        'Y', 'Z'
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String originalId = "999999999999999999";
        System.out.println("originalId = " + originalId);

        String newId = getBase62From10(originalId);
        System.out.println("newId = " + newId);

        String retrieveOriginalId = getBase10From62(newId);
        System.out.println("retrieveOriginalId = " + retrieveOriginalId);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param number a positive number in base 10
     *
     * @return the same number, in base 62
     */
    public static String getBase62From10(String number) {
        char[] buf = new char[number.length()];
        int charPos = number.length() - 1;

        BigInteger i = new BigInteger(number);
        BigInteger radix = BigInteger.valueOf(62);

        while (i.compareTo(radix) >= 0) {
            buf[charPos--] = DIGITS[i.mod(radix).intValue()];
            i = i.divide(radix);
        }
        buf[charPos] = DIGITS[i.intValue()];

        return new String(buf, charPos, (number.length() - charPos));
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param number a positive number in base 62
     *
     * @return the same number, in base 10
     */
    public static String getBase10From62(String number) {
        BigInteger value = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (char c : number.toCharArray()) {
            value = value.multiply(RADIX);
            if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
                value = value.add(BigInteger.valueOf(c - '0'));
            }
            if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
                value = value.add(BigInteger.valueOf(c - 'a' + 10));
            }
            if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
                value = value.add(BigInteger.valueOf(c - 'A' + 36));
            }
        }
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need clarifications:
- You suggested 36 radix because it's 10 digits + 26 small letters - am I right?
- Is this assures a unique String?
- Can you please explain how to make it an 11-chars string? How do I know what radix should be?
I started using a lower radix and when I arrived to 15 it gave me an 11 chars string.
In that case, it means that the used chars will be 0-9 and a-e?
In such case, does it assure the uniqueness?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: @AsafLevy I have added more details. (i) the maximum radix is 36, which will use digits (0 to 9) and small caps (a to z) only (ii) lower radixes will use less letters (iii) uniqueness is guaranteed if your original ids are unique

Comment: I have also added the code to convert back to the original id.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but the thing is that I can't limit myself to digits + a subset of letters; the requirement is to get an alpha-numeric string that might include digits + all optional letters, (lower/upper). This is in order to have as many options as possible when I change an X digits string to a new unique one. This is why I believe that a third party package would be more appropriate here - IT'S JUST THAT I DON'T FIND SUCH ONE ! Again, thanks for your help !

Comment: @AsafLevy Your requirement is not clear then: "*Our client wants to create a SECOND unique string which its length needs to be 11 chars and it should include alpha-numeric chars*". The approach I proposed transforms an 12-digit unique id into a 11-char alphanumerical unique id, which seemed to fulfill that. If the second string *has to* be a mix of digits, lower and upper case letters, you should make it clearer.

Comment: @AsafLevy No problem, but you should edit your question to explain what you need *exactly* if you want appropriate answers.

Comment: I edited the question; please let me know if it's clear enough now, thanks!

Comment: @AsafLevy Thanks - good news is that even with 19 digits it is technically possible: all digits + upper/lower char = 62 possible characters, and 62 ^ 11 > 10 ^ 19. The intuitive way is to convert to/from base 62, but I don't know of a built-in algo that does that. The other answr proposes base 64, which add 2 characters (generally one of `.+-/_=!:`). If you can live with the extra 2 characters, that is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @AsafLevy I have modified my answer.

Comment: I just saw your edited code which, I believe, has 2 issues: 1) The generated values are "consecutive" in some way, as follows: - for '999999999999999999' the output is '1bS0EMtBbK7' - for '999999999999999998' the output is '1bS0EMtBbK6' - for '999999999999999997' the output is '1bS0EMtBbK5' This, I believe, can be solved by some obfuscator class - am I right here? 2) For "low" numbers; e.g. those who start with '1' or with '0', the output is less then 11 digits. What is your suggestion for such case? just add zeroes at the beginning of the output? Thanks...

Comment: @AsafLevy for small numbers you can add 0s. Yes the new numbers are consecutive if the original ones are - you did not mention that you also needed obfuscation or some random component!

Comment: My initial problem was getting an 11 chars string from a 19 digits one. Your solution - which is what I needed :) - raised the need for obfuscation :) I assume that obfuscation is better then using random component in case I need in the future to re-generate the original 19 digits string - am I right? Is there a Java core obfuscator class that supports also de-obfuscating?

Comment: @AsafLevy I am not sure - you could ask a new question about that I guess (I've got an 11-char string and need to obfuscate it with a resersible algorithm).